# ABPersonSetImageData Only Altering the Contact Thumbnail and Not the Full Pic

Tags: iphone, addressbook, image

I am trying to add a border around each contact photo.  I have working code to create this bordered image and working code to set it as the contact image:

```
if (image) {
    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
    CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
    CFErrorRef error;
    ret = ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);
    if (ret) {
        ret = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    } else {
        DebugLog(@"Could not write the image to the person: %@", [error description]);
    }
    CFRelease(cfdata);
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that while the bordered image shows up correctly in the thumbnail when viewing in the Contacts or Phone app, the full-screen image displayed on an incoming call is not.

I originally thought it was just zoomed in a little so I experimented with the border size.  I confirmed that the border is not showing at all on the large shot.  Am I missing something obvious?

---

EDIT 10/9/09
I have been in communications with Apple and this is indeed a bug in the Address Book framework.  If you are reading this post, then I suggest you [file a bug with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) at to help expedite the fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here as I think I figured out what is the issue.  If your contact does NOT already have an image, both the thumbnail and the full sized shot will be added when you use `ABPersonSetImageData`.  If your contact has a full-sized image already, ONLY the thumbnail will be set when you use `ABPersonSetImageData`.

After realizing this, the solution is a no-brainer.  I just remove the pic right before setting it.

```
if (image) {
    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
    CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
    CFErrorRef error;

    ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error); // <-- clean any image first from ref
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
                
    ret = ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);
    if (ret) {
        ret = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    } else {
        DebugLog(@"Could not write the image to the person");
    }
    CFRelease(cfdata);
}
```

NOTE*

> This creates a square version of the full-sized pic.  The process
> crops the top and bottom off of the image and sets it to be `320x320`.
> But, it is working.

EDIT 10/9/09

> I have been in communications with Apple and this is indeed a bug in
> the Address Book framework.  If you are reading this post, then I
> suggest you [file a bug with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) at to help expedite the fix.

Comment: I followed this and i could replace the image, but it still shows the thumbnail pic when a call comes...
I tried deleting the pic manually and replace it by the code. But no use.

I wonder if this works?

thanks