# Setting Address Book image for a contact doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, debugging, uiimage, addressbook, peoplepicker

I'm trying to set the contact image with the code below. I am not seeing any errors, and the image is not saved to the contact entry in the address book. Please help! I must be doing something wrong...

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
[abcontroller setDisplayedPerson:person];

UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(im);
CFErrorRef error;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 

NSLog(@"Error:",error);
    if (ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, &error))
    {
        NSLog(@"Set contact photo %@", error);
        if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook))
        {
            NSLog(@"Changes made to address book");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"No changes made to address book");
        }

        if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error))
        {
            NSLog(@"Saved");

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Not saved");
        }


    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error saving contact photo %@", error);
    }
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    

return NO;
}
```

Here is my output log:

```
2010-01-17 21:58:35.465 Error:
2010-01-17 21:58:35.504 Set contact photo <ABPeoplePickerNavigationController: 0x19e9b0>
2010-01-17 21:58:43.497 No changes made to address book
2010-01-17 21:58:44.724 Saved
```

I'm not sure why the error object is logging as an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController object?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527658/abpersonsetimagedata-only-altering-the-contact-thumbnail-and-not-the-full-pic

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at that post this afternoon, and I'm not even getting as far as seeing a thumbnail assigned to a contact. I have also tried the above code, with the addition of clearing the contact's image before setting it. No such luck unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding *I'm not sure why the error object is logging as an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController object?* -- because you're not properly initialising the `error` here:

```
CFErrorRef error;
```

Assign `nil` here, or it will have a random (or more precisely, some previous memory) value, incidentally pointing to an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` object.

Regarding the merits: are you sure the reference to `person` you have passed to your method is valid in the context of the address book? I would try to use a function such as `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` first, instead of passing `ABPersonRef`s around and expecting them to be valid for different address book references.

Comment: Brilliant. My error is now Null, meaning that I guess there was no error. So, I wonder why the image isn't being saved...?

Comment: Please see the last change in my question. Try to change an image of a person you get from the address book you create within this method. If this works, that means you can't just re-use ABPersonRefs and have to rely on record IDs or something similar.

Comment: So, I need to return the record ID of the ABPersonRef I get from the picker...and then use ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID to perform the setimagedata on? :)

Comment: Basically, yes. Disclaimer: I haven't done it myself, but my gut tells me it's certainly worth a try to investigate.

Comment: Aha! It works! Thank you so much :) If you don't mind explaining, I'd be interested to know what's going on behind the scenes - howcome the addressbook is context sensitive? Also, I have an odd feeling I need to release all of these objects, right?

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, I've never used this part of the API. However, from general programming experience - if you **create** something (e.g. an address book), **retrieve objects** from there (person objects) and then **release** it (save & release the reference), I would **never** trust objects retrieved in the middle of this operation to be valid. This is because basically, then can be references to some data structures that the address book holds in memory until you destroy it. They are not meaningful to another address book created later.

Comment: As for the memory - yes, you have to release the address book (because the name of the method has `Create` in it). See this guide http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/300-BasicObjects/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1 to working with AB objects - it has a sample code which shows `CFRelease` at the end.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the guide I linked to previously says: **Important: Record objects cannot be passed across threads safely. Instead, you should pass the corresponding record identifier. See “Using Record Identifiers” for more information.** This implies what I hinted at about not using these objects not only after you destroy the book, but even while it's still alive, but in a different thread.

Answer (score 5):

All these answer didn't work.
You should simply change your line of code from:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

to:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];
```

This way you get the reference to the "address book", "person" belongs to.

Comment: After trying a lot and reading a lot this finally worked for me.  If I could vote you up more than once I would, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have also try to use to set the image (Photo) of current selected person but it display massage to saved successfully but in real it dose not work!!!

after the digging out the code and the documents provided by Apple SDK, i have some up with the following solution.

Please check out the below code. its really working fine for me  and hope for you also.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    @try {
        CFErrorRef cfError = nil;

        if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
            NSLog(@"%s has an image", _cmd);

            //theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact already has an image" message:@"Are you sure you want to overwrite it?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Overwrite"];
            //[theAlert show];
            //[theAlert release];
            //Note: We do not yet handle the answer to this question
        }

        // Just a sanity check

        if ((nil == [imageView image])
            || (nil == UIImagePNGRepresentation([imageView image]))) {
            NSLog(@"%s NIL STUFF", _cmd);
        }

        // Not sure I even need to create and save an address book
        // Cf. https://devforums.apple.com/message/27512#27512
        ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = ABAddressBookCreate();
        ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef) (UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imageView image], 1.0f)), &cfError);
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(libroDirec, person, &cfError);
        if (ABAddressBookSave(libroDirec, nil)) {
            NSLog(@"%s saved successfuly", _cmd);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%s something bad happen while saving", _cmd);
        }
        CFRelease(libroDirec);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {

    }
    @finally {

    }
    // TODO: release peoplePicker (and refactor code to not have it global)
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;

}
```

Comment: Had to  replace the line ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = ABAddressBookCreate(); according to the other answer in this post.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and it doesn't work as it should. So I made 2 changes.

```
ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = [peoplePicker addressBook];//don't create
        ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(display.image), &cfError);
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(libroDirec, person, &cfError);

        if (ABAddressBookSave(libroDirec, nil)) {
            NSLog(@"\n%s saved successfuly", _cmd);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"\n%s something bad happen while saving", _cmd);
        }
        //CFRelease(libroDirec);
```

Now it works as it supposed to.