# Change contact picture of a person in addressbook

Tags: iphone, ios4, addressbook

I'm creating an app in which i need to replace contact image of the person stored in iphone's address book from my image. Any Help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
```

Comment: i'm sorry but this is not working for me. I'm testing this in Simulator. Is their something else that i need to add in this code?

Comment: ya for that you have to implement http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thnx @PJR i finally solved my problem by this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082845/setting-address-book-image-for-a-contact-doesnt-seem-to-work