# How to save image to iphone's AddressBook using SDK API?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

My purpose is to process one image from image library, and save this image directly to one person record (i,e, "Tom" ), which is selected from AddressBook, I can see the new image replace Tom's previous image, but I can not save it to AddressBook.

I implemented delegate ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, and using following logics, but whatever I tried, modified records can not be saved to address books.

Any clues or suggest ? Thanks

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook= ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    BOOL wantToSaveChanges = YES;

    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Shi", &error);//, &error)

    NSData * dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cellImage);
    ABPersonSetImageData(person, dataRef, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {\
        NSLog(@"need to save ");
        if (wantToSaveChanges) {
            ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
        } else {
            ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
        }
    }else {
        NSLog(@"no changes");
    }

    if (error != NULL) {/*... Handle error. ...*/
        NSLog(@"error happened here " );

    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: What is the error (`CFShow(error);`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[Setting Address Book image for a contact doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082845/setting-address-book-image-for-a-contact-doesnt-seem-to-work)

and

[ABPersonSetImageData Only Altering the Contact Thumbnail and Not the Full Pic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527658/abpersonsetimagedata-only-altering-the-contact-thumbnail-and-not-the-full-pic)