# Setting user display picture

Tags: macos, cocoa, uiimage, abaddressbook

Is it possible to set the users display picture with Cocoa?

I can get the image from [`ABAddressBook`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I don't know a way of setting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ABPersonSetImageData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonSetImageData).

This post also shows how the thumbnail is manipulated: [ABPersonSetImageData Only Altering the Contact Thumbnail and Not the Full Pic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527658/abpersonsetimagedata-only-altering-the-contact-thumbnail-and-not-the-full-pic)